# Weak convergence in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

For a uniformly bounded sequence $(f_n)$ in $C[0,1]$, show that

$f_n$ converges weakly to $0$ $\iff $ $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(y) =0$ for all $y \in [0,1]$ 
Is the equivalence true if we do not assume that $(f_n)$is uniformly bounded,explain?

My first confusion, is $C[0,1]$ Hilbert space? I think it is not because this space is dense in $L^2[0,1]$ so it not closed subspace $L^2$ so not Hilbert space then how could the concept of weak convergence comes here? I'm confused, could anybody plz help me. I'm preparing for qualifying exam in august so I'm writing many questions frequently. I, really appreciate any kind of help..

Comment: $C[0,1]$ is not a Hilbert space in its usual topology, but the notion of weak convergence is defined on any topological vector space (in particular, on any Banach space). $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ if and only if for every bounded linear functional $g$, $g(f_n) \to g(f)$ (in the sense of the real or complex numbers).

Comment: what kind of operation is $g(f_n)$, $g$ applied to $f_n$?, I'm confused, could you please prove for me..

Comment: $g$ is a bounded linear functional; this means it is a continuous function from $C[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I mean, in $L^p(a,b)$ $g(f_n)=\int_a^b f_ng$ but how $g(f_n)$ is defined on $C[0,1]$?

Comment: You misunderstand. For $L^p$, we have $h_g(f_n) = \int_0^1 f_n g$; $h_g$ is the bounded linear functional, not $g$. The abuse of notation that tends to follow from the Riesz theorem makes this point somewhat tricky.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, in the similar fashion $g_t(f_n)=f_n(t)$  in $C[0,1]$ where $g_t$ is bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$, $t\in [0,1]$. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct. This is actually the same type of object when viewed in the right light; it can be shown that all bounded linear functionals on $C[0,1]$ (or on $C(X)$ for any compact metric space $X$) are given by integration against Borel measures. In the case of your $g_t$ it is given by the measure $\delta(A)$ which is $1$ if $t \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(E,\lVert\cdot\rVert)$ is a normed space, then we say that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges weakly to $x$ if for each linear continuous functional $f$ on $E$, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

There is no need to consider a Hilbert space in this context and actually $C[0,1]$ endowed with the uniform norm is not a Hilbert space (the parallelogram identity does not hold).

To check the equivalence, for one direction, consider the linear continuous functional $f_t\colon x\in C[0,1]\mapsto x(t)$. The other is more difficult unless we know a characterization of the topological dual space of $C[0,1]$ with Radon measures. Here, since $[0,1]$ is compact, we know that a continuous linear functional can be represented by a Borel (signed) measure on the unit interval (no need to consider Radon measures). The crucial fact is that if $\mu$ is a positive Borel measure on the unit interval and $\varepsilon\gt 0$, then there exists an integer $N$ and $a_1,\dots,a_N\in\mathbf R$, $c_1,\dots,c_N\in [0,1]$ such that 
$$\forall h\in C[0,1],\quad \left|\int_{[0,1]}h(x)\mu(dx)-\sum_{j=1}^Nc_jh(a_j)\right|\lt\varepsilon.$$

Recall a that weakly convergent sequence in a normed space is necessarily bounded.

Comment: I'm sorry, $f_t(x)=f(t)$ or $=x(t)$,for $t\in [0,1]$

Comment: One direction I proved, could you please prove next direction even though it is tough because same question may come in the exam. Once you do i will take the time to understand it..

Comment: What do you mean by "one direction"?

Comment: i mean if $f_n$ weakly converge to $0$ $\implies  f_n(y) \to 0 $. Actually, I did both direction (if and only if). If you do complete solution i would make sure if mine is correct.

Comment: it is because i have just started learning about weak convergence and i don't know many thing about weak convergence...

Comment: I've edited. Is it clearer?

Comment: Thanks, i will take time to understand it...

Comment: "The crucial fact" about positive Borel measure: what is this property commonly called? Could you give some reference?